# What is the significance of plugging in time in the following question?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

The problem is:

> A lunch pail is accidentally kicked off as steel beam on a building under construction. Suppose that the original horizontal speed is $1.5$ m/s. How far does the lunch pail fall after it travels $3.50$m horizontally?

So, a fairly easy problem:

1. $t=\frac{d}{v} = \frac{3.5}{1.5}\ \mathrm s = 2.3\ \mathrm s$
2. $y= 0.5\cdot(9.8)\cdot 2.3^2$
3. $y=26.7\ \mathrm m$

It falls $26.7\ \mathrm m$, what I do not understand however is why time is plugged into the kinematic equation since I understand that it is the time that the object took to travel $3.5\ \mathrm m$ horizontally initially. Isn't the time in the equation supposed to represent the total time the object travelled in the air? I am confused.

Comment: Why do you think that the total time that the object travelled horizontally in this problem is different from the total time that the object was traveling in the air?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When it is 3.5 m out horizontally, it is the $y$ meters down vertically.
- So, if it is the 3.5 m out horizontally **after time $t$,** where is it then vertically  at that moment?

It is the $y$ meters down, of course. The horizontal and vertical distances share the time $t$.

Comment: I  think this is what the question was implying, it was just phrased in an ambiguous manner.

Answer (score 2):

The time in the equation represents some time during the projectile motion.  The equations all relate to what you choose as the coordinates and initial conditions.

In this case you want to find how far it falls after it travels a horizontal distance.  So the time in this case should represent time in the air until the point of interest.

Now that you have that point of interest (time to travel 3.5 m horizontal) you can plug it into the equation for y and solve if done appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer I can think to give is that time has *no spacial direction* (it is a scalar quantity).

Now the velocity and displacement are vector quantities which can each be split into horizontal and vertical components.

The time associated with the horizontal component of either is **exactly the same** as the time associated with the vertical component.

Why must this be the case?

---

Well here are two examples that will give you a 'feel' for the physics that is taking place:

1.

> A long time ago when I was first being taught kinematics and
>   projectile motion we watched an experiment where two identical
>   metallic balls (equal in size and weight) held in a mechanical device
>   on the edge of the table. The device launches one of the balls
>   horizontally off a table and at exactly the same instant it drops the
>   other ball (which just falls straight down vertically to the floor.
>
> We observed that each of the balls hit the ground at *exactly* the
>   same time (with as much precision that our eyes allowed us to see
>   anyhow).

2.

> Another device we saw was an electronic device that fires a metallic
>   ball at a target (which is another identical metallic
>   ball). At the moment the ball is launched the target ball is released via some
>   magnetic 'switch'.
>
> No matter how fast the ball was fired at the target ball they will
>   always intercept (collide). In fact even if you used a gun to fire a
>   bullet at the target, as long as the bullet and the target are released/launched simultaneously you are guaranteed to hit the target everytime.

---

The fundamental reason why these two effects *must* take place is because (ignoring relativistic effects) time is *universal* (it is the same for both balls). In your example the lunch pail 'doesn't care' whether it is being fired horizontally or not it will always take the **same amount of time** to descend to a certain height. So even if you simply dropped the lunch pail, it will still take the same amount of time to reach a certain depth as if it was launched horizontally instead.

Comment: I understand that it takes the same time if dropped/projected at the same height but the question did not specify if the object continued to travel horizontally or whether it came at rest. This is what confused me but now I understand that it could have been worded better.